# Need to read relevant JSON data on home.html page with click

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have this JSON in my `home.ts`

```
  public json_html = {
    "button1":"<p><b>first section<b></p>",
    "button2":"<p>second section</p>",
    "button3":"<p><b>third section<b></p>",
  }
```

On my `home.html` I want to see three links - **button1 , button2 , button3** . If button 1 is clicked, then need to show its data using code like this:

```
document.getElementById("c1").innerHTML+= "clicked content";
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you might have more buttons, so let's build a loop. But first, Angular2's ngFor directive doesn't let you iterate over objects, they must be arrays. So we can grab get a array of keys first in your constructor:

```
this.buttons = Object.keys(this.json_html);
```

Then we can utilize the ngFor directive in our home.html

```
<button ion-button *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="selectedButton = button">
  {{ button }}
</button>
```

And then we can add to home.html a div to show the html data:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedButton" [innerHtml]="json_html[selectedButton]">
</div>
```

Now this is really simple, because your coding your HTML into the JSON object. I'd suggest looking at a tabs example project on Ionic when the data gets more complex.

Comment: If i need to make another button sub menu of button1, lets say `"button4-subof-button1" : :"<p>sub section of button 1</p>"`, then what is the best way to do this ??

Comment: If your sub-buttons are limited, you can try this:
Add that to a json_sub_html object.
    `this.subButtons = Object.keys(this.json_sub_html);`
Then utilize this in the template:
     `<button ng-if="selectedButton === 'button1' (click)="selectedSubButton = subButtons[0]"> {{ subButtons[0] }} </button>`

Show subbutton text:
     `<div *ngIf="selectedSubButton" [innerHtml]="json_sub_html[selectedButton]">
     </div>`

If you're going to have a lot of sub buttons, you can try embedding the subbutton objects as a part of your json_html object.

Comment: i added `<p contenteditable="true">this is editable content</p>` but on page when i inspect, `contenteditable="true"` is not visible , how can i make it visible

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you should follow this steps:

1. Create an array of object keys using `this.keysArr = Object.keys(this.json_html)`, because we can't iterate through objects in view
2. Iterate through this keys using `<div *ngFor="let button of keysArr"></div>`
3. Inside the `div` from step 2, declare another one: `<div [innerHTML]="json_html[button]"></div>`

I'm using `[innerHTML]` instead of the regular `document.getElementById("c1").innerHTML+= "clicked content"`, because it looks like "the Angular way". Here is the working example (in `app` folder):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pyhg3?file=app/button-overview-example.html

**UPDATE**

*"It is showing me data of all 3 together, i want to see `button1`, `button2`, `button3` and on clicking it to show data of the clicked element. Whereas currently it is directly showing data, can you update stackblitz"*

Sure, here it is:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pyhg3-e49qys?file=app/button-overview-example.html

Comment: it is showing me data of all 3 together, i want to see `button1` , `button2`, `button3` and on clicking it to show data of the clicked element. Whereas currently it is directly showing data, can you update stackblitz

Comment: i added `<p contenteditable="true">this is editable content</p>` but on page when i inspect, `contenteditable="true"` is not visible , how can i make it visible

Comment: @user2828442 can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: just update this line in your stackblitz -  "button1":'<p contenteditable="true"><b>first section<b></p>',

Comment: this may work for us but i am unable to use this, if you can then it might be helpful

Comment: @user2828442 That attribute is stripped for security reasons, but we can use `DomSanitizer` to tell Angular, that it's safe: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pyhg3-hltuem?file=app/button-overview-example.ts